# Meida, Deletion, New User

Tags: media

Hello i have a 2007 acer laptop my mom wants all her old media to not be deleted upon me using it. Windows 7 is now expired and I need to put an os on the laptop asap. Will my media be deleted if i use ubuntu as my new os? I have been considering switching to ubuntu it looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Windows 7 can expire, unless it was never properly activated.

Regardless, if you install another OS (such as Ubuntu...you will like it) and you choose to replace your old OS, then it will overwrite your hard drive, effectively wiping everything. Depending on the amount of media to be saved, I suggest buying or borrowing an external hard drive and copying everything to it. Then, when you have Ubuntu up and running, you can copy all the media back to the computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you select something along the lines of "Install along existing os" when installing Ubuntu it shouldn't delete anything.

But copying the files somewhere else and then wiping the hard drive by selecting "replace old os" on installing Ubuntu is probably the better solution, if Windows isn't working anyway.